# Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

```
this is my php file and i have error in line no 3 
Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in D:\trainee\xampp\htdocs\traineeproject\sil1online\bottom.php on line 3
```

when i am useing this seesion variable everytime that give me error...

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$smarty->assign("s_activId",isset($_SESSION['s_activId'])   ? $_SESSION['s_activId'] : ");
$smarty->assign("l_tital",$l_tital);
$smarty->assign("l_home",$l_home);
$smarty->assign("l_billBook",$l_billBook);
$smarty->assign("l_addBillBook",$l_addBillBook);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `$smarty` object defined here.

You should have after setting time zone something like that:

```
require 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

to be able to use Smarty methods

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Smarty in D:\trainee\xampp\htdocs\traineeproject\sil1online\include\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1595

Comment: @user1866385 if you've already included this file, you need to use only `$smarty = new Smarty();` here